# estimate gas prices with ethers js (gasprice)

Tags: typescript, transactions, blockchain, web3js, ethers.js

**how i can fix the gas price estimate.**
*i try this code*

```
try {
    const balance = await burnWallet.getBalance();

    if (balance.isZero()) {
      console.log(`Balance is zero`);
      return;
    }

    const gasPrice = balance.div(21000);

    if (gasPrice.lt(1e9)) {
      console.log(
        `Balance too low to burn (balance=${formatEther(
          balance,
        )} gasPrice=${gasPriceToGwei(gasPrice)}) Gwei`,
      );
      return;
    }

    const leftovers = balance.sub(gasPrice.mul(21000));

    console.log(`Leftovers: ${formatEther(leftovers)} ETH`);

    const nonce = await burnWallet.provider.getTransactionCount(
      burnWallet.address,
    );

    const tx = await burnWallet.sendTransaction({
      to: flashbotsBeerFund,
      gasLimit: 21000,
      gasPrice,
      nonce,
      value: leftovers,
    });

    console.log(`Burning ${formatEther(balance)} ETH`);
    console.log(`Sent tx with nonce ${tx.nonce} to ${flashbotsBeerFund}`);
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.log(`Error sending tx: ${err.message ?? err}`);
  }
```

how i can fix this error

I am trying to make a simple js bot that checks every block for eth(or the main token of the chain) and sends it to another wallet.